# Centralizers of semisimple subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, centralisers

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$If $G$ is a simple Lie group, and $\rho: G \to \GL(V)$ is a representation, then by Schur's lemma, the group of automorphisms of $\rho$ is a reductive subgroup of $\GL(V)$. I'm wondering whether this generalizes to the case where $\GL(V)$ is replaced by an arbitrary reductive group?

More generally: if $G$ is a semisimple algebraic group (or even reductive), $H$ is a reductive algebraic group, and $\rho : G \to H$ is a homomorphism, is the centralizer of the image of $\rho$ in $H$, $C_{H}(\rho(G))$, a reductive subgroup of $H$?

Edits:

1. The case I'm most interested is when the field is $\mathbb{C}$, but I would be interested in hearing about other cases as well.
2. As pointed out in the comments, in the case $G = H$, the centralizer is the centre, which is reductive but not necessarily connected. So the centralizer may not be connected in the general case as well.

Comment: Note that there is no difference between handling the reductive, the semisimple, and the simple cases:  $G$ is covered by the product of its simple subgroups and a central torus, and so we may as well regard the representation as coming from that product; the centraliser of a torus is always reductive; and then we reduce the case of $G$ a product of simple factors to the simple case by induction.  (One still has to worry about simple vs absolutely simple, though.)

Comment: You probably also need to specify whether you want to require characteristic $0$, or algebraic closure (which I guess you don't since you begin by talking about (presumably real) Lie groups).  In positive characteristic I think you'll run into trouble with non-completely reducible representations.

Comment: algebraic closure of a ground field is irrelevant because being reductive (in char. 0) is absolute.

Comment: Your definition of 'reductive' doesn't require 'connected', right?  Otherwise it is easy to come up with counterexamples (e.g., $G = H = \operatorname{SL}_2$).

Comment: Thats a good point. I guess more generally, if $G = H$, then the centralizer is just the centre, which is reductive but not necessarily connected.

Comment: Centralizers of semisimple elements are reductive.  Let's suppose that H is connected. Semisimple elements are Zariski-dense in H. By dimension reasons, finitely many suffice, of which you even can assume that they are pairwise conjugate, as you can take one regular element and use the fact that all maximal tori are conjugate. Hence all you need to show is that the intersection of finitely many conjugates of a reductive group is reductive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In characteristic zero, the connected closed subgroups of $G$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the Lie subalgebras of ${\rm Lie}(G)={\mathfrak g}$, and <strike>the Killing form</strike> a suitably chosen symmetric bilinear $G$-equivariant form on ${\mathfrak g}$ is non-degenerate. *In fact we can choose this form to be the trace form for a rational representation for $G$.* Since <strike>the Killing form</strike> this form is $G$-equivariant, it is $H$-equivariant, and irreducible summands for non-isomorphic $H$-submodules are orthogonal. Hence the <strike>Killing</strike> form on ${\mathfrak g}$ restricts to a non-degenerate form on ${\mathfrak g}^H={\rm Lie}(Z_G(H)^\circ)$.

I now claim that if $K$ is a connected algebraic group with a non-degenerate trace form $\kappa$ arising from a rational representation $\rho:K\rightarrow {\rm GL}(V)$, then $K$ is reductive. Indeed, if the unipotent radical $R_u(K)$ is non-trivial then $\rho(R_u(K))$ is a unipotent subgroup of ${\rm GL}(V)$, so after conjugation is contained in the subgroup of upper-triangular unipotent matrices, so the restriction of $\kappa$ to ${\mathfrak u}={\rm Lie}(R_u(K))$ is zero. Since ${\mathfrak u}$ is an ideal of ${\rm Lie}(K)$, this contradicts the non-degeneracy of the form. In particular, $Z_G(H)^\circ$ is reductive.

Comment: What is the Killing form on a reductive (as opposed to semisimple) group?  Do you restrict from some embedding into $\operatorname{SL}(V)$?

Comment: Good point - I guess I just mean that there exists a $G$-equivariant symmetric bilinear form on ${\mathfrak g}$. Any such form (it doesn't have to be the Killing form) will work for this argument.

Comment: I think another step is needed, because the Lie algebra of $\mathbb G_a$ also has a nondegenerate form.

Comment: Ok, I want the form to be a trace form - I'm fairly sure ${\rm Lie}({\mathbb G}_a)$ can't have a non-degenerate form coming from a rational representation for ${\mathbb G}_a$.

Comment: Could you please give some more detail? (Also, in your answer, are your $G$ and $H$ flipped from the notation in the question?)

Comment: Apologies, yes I did flip $G$ and $H$. I have included some more detail - I'm not sure what else you think is unclear.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! Although I am not sure that closed connected subgroups of $G$ are in $1-1$ correspondence with Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}$ in the case that $G$ is only reductive. But this doesn't seem to affect the argument.

Comment: Could I ask a follow-up question? Given the case $\rho : \mathbb{C}^{*} \to H$ (or more generally given a real semisimple element of the Lie algebra), the centralizer is a Levi subgroup of a parabolic associated to $\rho$. Is there a generalization of this in the setting of my question?

Comment: For a semisimple element of $H$, the centraliser is a pseudo-Levi subgroup (subset of the affine Dynkin diagram). For an arbitrary subgroup of $H$, I think almost anything can occur, e.g. there is an $F_4$ in $E_8$ with centraliser equal to $G_2$ (and vice versa). The centralisers of ${\rm SL} _2$s are the "reductive parts" of centralisers of nilpotent elements, so can be found e.g. in Collingwood-McGovern ("Nilpotent Orbits...") or Carter's "Finite Groups of Lie type" (with some subtleties around component groups).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something simple, but I can't follow the last step. We have $\mathfrak{u}$ an ideal of $Lie(K)$ consisting of upper triangular matrices. Why does this contradict the non-degeneracy of the trace form?

Comment: Levi decomposition ${\rm Lie}(K)={\mathfrak l}\ltimes({\mathfrak s}\oplus{\mathfrak u})$ where ${\mathfrak l}$ is semisimple, ${\mathfrak s}$ is a torus and ${\mathfrak s}\oplus{\mathfrak u}$ is the radical. Now ${\mathfrak l}$ is perfect and we can assume ${\mathfrak s}$ consists of diagonal matrices.

Comment: I'm not seeing why this helps

Comment: Sorry, scratch that. Easy explanation: let $x\in{\rm Lie}(K)$ and $y\in{\mathfrak u}$. Then there's a Borel subalgebra ${\mathfrak b}$ of ${\rm Lie}(K)$ containing $x$, and then ${\mathfrak u}$ is contained in the nilradical of ${\mathfrak b}$, and we may assume ${\mathfrak b}$ consists of upper triangular matrices, then it's easy to see ${\rm tr}(xy)=0$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!