# Reference request: Criterion for a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ being reductive in terms of the trace

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a complex algebraic group embedded into $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. A criterion for $G$ to be reductive is the following. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$, and let $B$ be the trace form of $\mathfrak{gl}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ restricted to $\mathfrak{g}$: $B(x,y) = \operatorname{Tr}(xy)$. Then $G$ is reductive if and only if $B$ is non-degenerate.

This criterion was used in an answer to one of my previous [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379869/centralizers-of-semisimple-subgroups). I think I also know how to prove it. It follows because the Lie algebra of the unipotent radical, $\mathfrak{r}$, is the kernel of $B$. The reason for this is roughly as follows: using a Levi decomposition, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ decomposes (as a vector space) into $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{r} \oplus \mathfrak{z} \oplus \mathfrak{s}$, where $\mathfrak{z}$ is abelian (the Lie algebra of a torus) and $\mathfrak{s}$ is semisimple. Since $\ker(B)$ is solvable, it must be contained in $\mathfrak{r} \oplus \mathfrak{z}$, which is the radical. But since $\mathfrak{z}$ is the Lie algebra of a torus, $B$ restricts to $\mathfrak{z}$ to be positive definite. On the other hand, we can choose a basis so that $\mathfrak{r} \oplus \mathfrak{z}$ lies in the upper triangular matrices, and this implies that $\mathfrak{r} \subseteq \ker B$.

I haven't been able to find this result anywhere in the literature. I am wondering if anyone knows where I can find it?

Comment: Bourbaki: Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, Chapter 1, Section 4, Proposition 5, p. 56

Comment: @FZaldivar, since this is specifically a reference request, I think [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426186/reference-request-criterion-for-a-subgroup-of-mathrmgl-n-mathbbc-bei#comment1095606_426186) is an answer!

Comment: @LSpice: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bourbaki: Lie Groups and Lie Algebras, Chapter 1, Section 4, Proposition 5, p. 56.

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, but this doesn't have precisely the same statement. It's phrased entirely for Lie algebras, in which case the statement is false. For example, $\mathbb{C}$ is reductive, but it can be embedded in $\mathfrak{gl}_{2}$ as strictly upper triangular, so that the trace form vanishes. It's only the representations induced from group representations that are guaranteed to have the desired property.

Comment: Do you happen to have the French-language reference for this?  For me, in the French-language version, Chapitre 1, Section 4, Proposition 5 is on p. 60—although of course page numbering will vary between the languages—and is a result about nilpotent Lie algebras.  But I always have a horrible time navigating the Byzantine Bourbaki numbering.

Comment: @LSpice: I have the English version, that is why the page numbering is different.

Comment: @unknownymous: Using that in
characteristic zero the connected closed subgroups of $G$
are in correspondence with the Lie subalgebras of $\text{Lie}(G)$ reduces the group statement to the Lie algebra one. But I don't have a reference for this part and I am a little unease about it.

Comment: @FZaldivar: What you say is true, but I don't think the Lie algebra alone can detect whether the group is reductive. For example, $\mathbb{C}$ is the Lie algebra of a reductive group ($\mathbb{C}^*$), and a unipotent group ($\mathbb{C}$). So I think it's key that in the criterion, $G$ is an algebraic group which is embedded into the general linear group.